# Combobox en Ribbon excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

Solicito de su ayuda con la respuesta a esta pregunta.

Estoy modificando la ribon de excel usando CustomUI xml y vba, dentro de esta modificacion pongo un combobox. lo que deseo saber es como puedo capturar el valor seleccionado en el combobox.

Comment: Yeison, si compartes el código o lo que has intentado hasta el momento los usuarios te podrán ayudar mejor. Por lo que preguntas he hecho una búsqueda rápida en google , coméntame si te sirve este link y adjunto la respuesta que exponen en la web [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/obtaining-ribbon-combobox-control-string-value.980176/)

Comment: Este es el XML uso   <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
 <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
  <tabs>
   <tab id="cobTab" label="Cobrando BPO" >
    <group id="bigroup" label="Business Intelligence">
     <comboBox id="listClientes" label="Clientes: " sizeString="1234567890123456789012345" getItemCount="modribbon.numeroClientes" getItemLabel="modribbon.textClientes" getItemID="modribbon.idClientes" >
     </comboBox>
    </group>
   </tab>
  </tabs>
 </ribbon>
</customUI>

Comment: Este es el vba que uso para cargar los datos                                                         Public Sub textClientes(Control As IRibbonControl, nroCliente As Integer, ByRef textOpcion, clienteSelecct As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        textOpcion = Worksheets("Listas").Cells(nroCliente + 1, 1)
End Sub  y lo que quiero es obtener el valor seleccionado en el combobox

Answer (score 0):

En respuesta a mi pregunta la soluciion fue la siguiente:
en el xml se debe agregar una propiedad mas llamada onChange="modribbon.changeClientes" dentro del combobox y en vba se debe llamar asi
Public Sub changeClientes(Control As IRibbonControl, clienteSelect As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    VarCliente = clienteSelect
end sub                                                                                      VarCliente la declaro como publica para poder acceder desde cualquier parte a ella